# Best way to parse string with delimiters (thinking regex)?

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, pattern-matching

I'm currently trying to parse a python string for some specific text inside of it. It should actually be really straightforward.

But more importantly, I want to know if regex is a "tool set" type thing, where you know a certain number of tricks? Some people are very, very proficient with them, and I want to attain that proficiency.

***So while I am asking how to match this string, I'd like an explanation of your thought process as you went through as you came to your solution***

I basically want text A, text-B, and text_C, delimited only by commas.

The desired output string:

```
"text A,text-B,text_C"
```

The original text is as follows:

```
"(1, u'text A', u'text-B', u'text_C')"
```

In my limited understand, I understand that the main thing separating each expression is a single-quote, so I would start with that. But ultimately I *might have strings such as `text-'A`* and I want to make sure that I don't run into errors because I parse the string incorrectly.

Thanks for your time. Remember: *thought process.*

Comment: why would you not use ast.literal_eval for something like this?

Comment: Probably because I've never heard of that... An abstract syntax tree? i'll look into it.

Comment: but in general, yes, regular expressions are an excellent tool, and you can find plenty of resources on the web to help understand them.

Comment: Well I was *honestly* hoping to kill two birds with one stone in this question. Later in my project I'll be searching through pages of extracted text looking for these expressions (like Test-A etc.)

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx Hey, so I've realized my problem may be a bit misguided.  As for the second part of my question, since regex is about pattern matching, am I just trying to find *similar* expressions to a given string? I think I broadcasted my misunderstanding quite well.

Comment: @jdero: The "ast" in `ast.literal_eval` does in fact stand for "abstract syntax tree", but really, that's not relevant here; it's just where this function happens to live. Burying it in the `ast` module, and naming it `literal_eval` when it actually evaluates things that aren't literals (collection displays made up, recursively, of nothing but literals), makes it very hard to discover. But it's very useful once you discover it.

Comment: @jdero: Anyway, part of the reason it's buried there is that it can actually take either a string or the AST node parsed from such a string. But mainly it's buried there to discourage people from trying to use `repr` and `literal_eval` when they should be using JSON or pickle or something else designed for interchange/persistence. Which is fine, but when someone's actually given you a Python `repr`… what else are you supposed to do with it?

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for being so thorough. What a silly name (literal when not)...

Comment: @jdero: Python actually has multiple conflicting definitions for what "literal" means. And the definition that `literal_eval` uses is especially fun, given that it includes list/set/etc. displays, but it doesn't include comprehensions, even though (since 3.0) comprehensions are a subset of displays…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the string you're dealing with is a repr version of a Python tuple, the most Pythonic way is to use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) which can take that object and safely convert back to a Python object retaining the correct types:

```
import ast
text = "(1, u'text A', u'text-B', u'text_C')"
tup = ast.literal_eval(text)
```

Then if you only wish to join each item that's a string together:

```
joined = ', '.join(el for el in tup if isinstance(el, basestring))
# text A, text-B, text_C
```

Otherwise just slice the tuple `tup[1:]` and join the items in that...

In terms of a regex, a quick and dirty, non-robust method, that will break easily and possibly even provide incorrect matches under some circumstances is to use:

```
import re
string_vals = re.findall("'(.*?)'", text)
```

This finds anything after a `'` up until the very next `'`... Again, using `ast.literal_eval` is much nicer here...

Answer (score 0):

Must it be regex? :(

```
a_str = "(1, u'text A', u'text-B', u'text_C')"
print ",".join(a_str[1:-1].split(",")[1:]).replace('u','').replace("'",'')
```

Yields:

```
text A, text-B, text_C
```

EDIT: well if it must be regex .. don't mind this post, it doesn't work for many cases.

Comment: you don't even need re.. sorry this wasn't regex. D:

Comment: Just curious, I kind of like the solution, is there a formal name for this (using .join, .split and .replace)? I've used them before but I want them to be on the tip of my tongue when I have problems like this...

Comment: string manipulation? <-- i made that up. in terms of regex though, i'm sure its just pattern matching. so you want to look for a pattern that matches all the things you want to find and express tha tpattern in terms of regex characters (found in doc nicely listed) EDIT: Though i never personally used regex. so i'm interested in a nice answer too! #toolazytopracticeregex

Comment: My question is possible using regex no? is it just really difficult?

Comment: Probably possible. Probably not very difficult. I'm probably just a newb.